# A dynamic load __import__ reports no module error

Tags: python, reflection, import, reload

Here is my directory structure:
[image]

In file keyword.py I import lottery.lottery at the first line like this:
from lottery.lotterya import Lottery
In file rule.py I import lottery.keyword dynamically like this:
__import('lottery.keyword') but it reports an error "No module named lotterya".
I don't know what to do. Can anyone help?

I dynamically import a module

Comment: I wonder if you remove "import lottery.lottery" in keyword.py, does that return wrong? does __init__.py exist in lottery? I am not sure whether you miss or you don't put it here.

Comment: If I remove "import lottery.lotterya" ,It can't find class Lottery, __init__.py has already existed in the package. In fact It reports No module named lotterya.

Comment: so it looks like dynamic imported file couldn't have static import defined inside, that's strange. I will write more when I have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for your question. It uses importlib to do dynamic import.

In ruly.py

```
import importlib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mKey = importlib.import_module('lottery.keyword')
    MyKeyword = getattr(mKey,'MyKeyword')
    k = MyKeyword()
    k.mPrint()
```

In keyword.py

```
from lottery.lotterya import Lotterya

class MyKeyword():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def mPrint(self):
        print 'Hello, keyword'
        l = Lotterya()
        l.lPrint()
```

In lotterya.py

```
class Lotterya:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def lPrint(self):
        print 'Hello, Lotterya'
```